# Azure Terraform Kubernetes VMSS user assigned identity

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am pretty lost here with this configuration and everything i tried, it didnt work at all.

To explain. I have a terraform code to deploy a Azure Kubernetes cluster, as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-${var.aks_name}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-${var.aks_name}"
  kubernetes_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
  node_resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name}-nrg"

  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "systempool"
    vm_size              = "Standard_D2_V2"
    orchestrator_version = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    zones                = [1]
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    min_count            = 1
    max_count            = 2
    os_disk_size_gb      = 64
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.system_pool_subnet.id
    node_labels = {
      "nodepool-type" = "System"
      "environment"   = "${var.environment}"
      "nodepoolOS"    = "linux"
      "app"           = "System"
    }
  }
```

What i wanted to do is to enable the systemAssigned and UserAssigned identity in my Virtual Machine Scale Set.

In the cluster configuration i did add the following.

```
identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_ids = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned.id
  }
```

But this does not add the existing managed identity i created.
So i thought i did something wrong and tried to use just the systemAssigned identity, but this also does not get enabled. I couldnt find any reference in terraform documentations or configurations.

So what i did i tried to run the az command:

```
az aks update -g <resource-group> -n <cluster-name> --enable-managed-identity
```

the above works, but not on the scale set, which is understandable.

Can please anyone address me on what i am doing wrong here?

What i want, is to enable and assigned the usermanaged identity to my VMSS, and possibly doing both (SystemAssigned and USerAssigned).

I hope i explained well my intentions, and if not please do not hesitate to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i wanted to do is to enable the **systemAssigned** and **UserAssigned identity** in my Virtual Machine Scale Set.

As you cannot assign both **systemAssigned** and **UserAssigned identity** to `VMSS` using Terraform, as it supports only one **Identity** block at a time.

> Note: If the `kubelet_identity` block is not specified in the code, the User Managed Identity is created automatically and assigned to the VMSS, but it will only accept a User Managed Identity, not **systemAssigned**

[image]

Here is the updated code to create `AKS` and enable an existing **UserAssigned identity** for `VMSS`

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name = "Venkat"
    }
    data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
      name                = "Aks-UAMI"
      resource_group_name = "Venkat"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
      location            = "East US "
      name                = "demovenkatakscluster1"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      dns_prefix          = "aks-demo"
      node_resource_group = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}-rg"
    
      default_node_pool {
        name                 = "systempool"
        vm_size              = "Standard_D2_V2"
        zones                = [1]
        enable_auto_scaling  = true
        min_count            = 1
        max_count            = 2
        os_disk_size_gb      = 64
        type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        node_labels = {
          "nodepool-type" = "System"
          "nodepoolOS"    = "linux"
          "app"           = "System"
        }
    
      }
      identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id]
      }
    
    kubelet_identity{
         client_id  = "user assigned identity Cleint ID"
         object_id = "user assigned identity Object ID"
          user_assigned_identity_id = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster)

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer. i tried the code suggested by you, but i am getting a permission error: ` Code="CustomKubeletIdentityMissingPermissionError" Message="The cluster using user-assigned managed identity must be granted 'Managed Identity Operator' role to assign kubelet identity` the cluster at this point still doesnt exists tho. Did you face the same issue by any chance?

Comment: Yes, please assign the **Managed Identity Operator**  role to an existing user-managed identity at either the resource group level or the subscription level.